USB device stops working for some reason
In my custom boat project i am using a Raspbery Pi. In order to get an engine telemetry (RPM and temperature) i connected a diagnostic adapter(ELM327 or "vag com kkl") to the engine OBD2 port.
But when RPM starts growing above to 3 000-ish, adapter stops working.
dmesg shows ftdi_sio ttyUSB0: usb_serial_generic_read_bulk_callback - urb stopped: -32
There are still /dev/ttyUSB0 device in the system, i still can open it, but there is no data. The only way to get it work again is to reboot the raspberry.
I have two boats, with different engines, different ECU and different OBD2 adapter with different USB-TTL chips in it. (FTDI and CH340). But have the same problem (!).
I glued the USB in order protect it from vibration, but it didn`t change a thing. BTW there are no significant vibration inside and other UBS devices such as 4G modem and MCU works just fine no matter what RMP engine runs.


Did you monitor the battery voltage and the stepdown regulator output voltage at varying engine RPM?

Did you verify where the problem is by connecting the OBD reader to completely separate battery powered laptop to see if the problem persists?
